# How to extract numbers from string and separate them by comma (or other separator) (substitute, replace, erase, isnumber, remove, delete, ...)

Tags: microsoft-excel, find-and-replace, extract, search-indexing, auto-detect

I need to extract numbers from a string in Excel and the numbers need to be separated by a comma as shown in row 3 (or any other separator).

[image]

I can extract the numbers in row 1 by:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MID(0&A1, LARGE(INDEX(ISNUMBER(--MID(A1, ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))), 1)) * ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))), 0), ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))))+1, 1) * 10^ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)))/10)´´´
```

Or in row 2 by:

```
=SUM(MID(0&A2,LARGE(INDEX(ISNUMBER(--MID(A2,ROW($1:$99),1))*ROW($1:$99),),ROW($1:$99))+1,1)*10^ROW($1:$99)/10)
```

However, I would need them to be separated somehow.

**NOTE:** I have up to 200 different combination of numbers and car brands, which cause simple substitute functions to reach their limits. I prefer a formula based solution without hidden interim columns if possible (certainly no manual mouse clicking). ***My VBA skill are low, but I'm open for new challenges!***

Comment: do you have TEXTJOIN?

Comment: I do have TEXTJOIN. Is this function specific to certain Excel versions? Compatibility across different versions is another issue of concern.

Comment: it is only available in 2019 and office 365.  Without it one would want to use vba if the number of numbers is not known.

Comment: I'm not into VBA, but can read and edit part of given macros. I have to have compatible with older Office version.

Comment: Well, if if has to be VBA, then I'll go for it even though I have little knowledge as I'm more in to R or Python.

Comment: What is the earliest version you need to deal with?  Power Query is available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365.

Comment: Do you have more columns to help us find the conditions.

Comment: The template is to be shared by users and the Excel version may go down to whatever is still out there. @Lee: Could extend your question pls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**
*It seems the **real** data is more complicated than the sample initially submitted.  The simplest way to program this is to use Regular Expressions to extract the numbers*

- Extract any digit string that follows either the start of the string; or a `comma` optionally followed by one or more `spaces`

***Edit2** Converted to late-binding after I read template will be distributed*

```
Option Explicit
Function extrNums(cellRef) As String
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object, M As Object
    Dim sTemp As Variant
    Const sPat As String = "(?:^|,\s*)(\d+)\b"
    
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .Pattern = sPat
    If .Test(cellRef) Then
        Set MC = .Execute(cellRef)
        For Each M In MC
            sTemp = sTemp & ", " & M.SubMatches(0)
        Next M
    End If
End With

extrNums = Mid(sTemp, 3)

End Function
```

[image]

**Regex Explanation**
***extract numbers***
(?:^|,\s*)(\d+)\b

Options: ^$ match at line breaks

- [Match the regular expression below](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(?:^|,\s*)`

  - [Match this alternative](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `^`

    - [Assert position at the beginning of the string](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^`
  - [Or match this alternative](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `,\s*`

    - [Match the character “,” literally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `,`
    - [Match a single character that is a “whitespace character”](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s*`

      - [Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`
- [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) `(\d+)`

  - [Match a single character that is a “digit”](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d+`

    - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
- [Assert position at a word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b`

Created with [RegexBuddy](https://www.regexbuddy.com/)

Comment: Hey that's so ... cool!

Comment: Maybe, just one last related question. If I were to do the opposite and keep only the text, I guess I would need to change only nums() in line: ```ReDim nums(0 To UBound(x))```  to the equivalent for text. Is it?

Comment: Dam! I found an issue. There are also items in my list containing a comma, e.g. "22 Audi (Model x, Model y)". Now it returns "22, Model"

Comment: @MsGISRocker See edited answer which handles your problem, and others

Comment: @MsGISRocker To return just the text portion is more complicated.

Comment: That was actually extremely helpful! U made me become a regex maniac!

Comment: I did post a follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68347914/regex-match-string-between-two-strings-within-an-excel-visiual-basich-applicati. Just in case. Thx MGR

Answer (score 5):

With Office 365 or 2019 Excel we can use TEXTJOIN and FILTERXML.

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,","," ")," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[number()=.]"))
```

The FILTERXML parses a made up string that looks like xml.  We substitute the spaces and the commas for `</s><s>` then only return the nodes that are numeric.

The TEXTJOIN takes the array returned and adds a comma between each element.

[image]

Without text join we can concatenate many:

```
IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,","," "),"  "," ")," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[number()=.][1]"),"")
```

The added `[1]` to the FILTERXML is which node to return.  So we can string a bunch together:

```
=IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,","," "),"  "," ")," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[number()=.][1]"),"")&
IFERROR(", "&FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,","," "),"  "," ")," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[number()=.][2]"),"")&
IFERROR(", "&FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,","," "),"  "," ")," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[number()=.][3]"),"")&
IFERROR(", "&FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,","," "),"  "," ")," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[number()=.][4]"),"")&
IFERROR(", "&FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,","," "),"  "," ")," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[number()=.][5]"),"")&
IFERROR(", "&FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,","," "),"  "," ")," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[number()=.][6]"),"")
```

This will do a max of 6, if there possibly can be more add more lines changing the number in the `[#]` to the next.

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid, but I cannot rely on the latest office version and as stated above I have more than 200 number string pairs.

Comment: Besides, the solutions work perfectly fine!

Comment: The second one, will work for anything 2013 and later.